# response.getOutputStream() throws IllegalStateException when called for the first time

Tags: java, jsp, download, response

I'm trying to Download a pdf from a MySQL-DB ( I get it as a Blob, and up to that point everything works just fine. But when I try to get the ServletOutputstream to send it to the client the programm crashes. 
AFAIK the exception is thrown when the method has been called before or the getwriter-method has. But I don't use the getwriter-method in my code at all and the other getOutPutStream-methods in the programm are not reached  (I commented them out to make sure). 
(The whole thing happens in a JSP if that matters for any reason)

Heres my code snippet and the Exception:

**Code**

```
Blob pdf = null;
if(request.getParameter("reportId") != null){
    pdf = testszenario.getReportErgebnisPdf(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("reportId")), request.getParameter("erzeugung"));
}
byte[] buf = new byte[(int)pdf.length()];
InputStream inputStream  = pdf.getBinaryStream();
inputStream.read(buf);
inputStream.close();
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment; filename=test.pdf"); 

ServletOutputStream sos = response.getOutputStream();
// response.getOutputStream().write(buf);
```

**Exception**

```
26.03.2013 09:28:29 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SCHWERWIEGEND: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.ServletResponseWrapperInclude.getOutputStream(ServletResponseWrapperInclude.java:63)
    at org.apache.jsp.jsp.modules.Testszenario.PostReportResultOverview_jsp._jspService(PostReportResultOverview_jsp.java:115)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:630)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:535)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:472)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:968)
    at org.apache.jsp.jsp.McFrame_jsp._jspService(McFrame_jsp.java:284)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:845)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check if your response is committed. If you try to do something on a committed response then `IllegalStateException` may arise. Response will be committed, if page buffer size is exceeded.

Comment: You are right, that was the problem. But since the response is committed already at the beginning of the JSP, before I even changed anything or wrote anything in the response-buffer, how can I change that?

Comment: But how is that possible? Even when I change the code to a minimum  of this:

`<%@page import="com.nundp.util.ResourceHandler,java.util.*,java.io.*,java.sql.Blob"%>
<%System.out.println("start jsp: " + response.isCommitted());%>`

the response is already commited?

Comment: Alright I found the mistake. The jsp was called through another "Frame"-jsp, which contains navigation etc., and thus the response was already committed. But since the called jsp is not for displaying purposes (I know thats really bad practice) theres no need to call it through the frame-jsp, and when adressing it directly it works. Thanks NilsH.

Answer (score 1):

It might indeed matter that you're doing this in a JSP. Keep in mind that the JSP is part of the output rendering phase of a web application request, so the container might have obtained the writer object already. Try moving your code into a servlet instead. It'll give you more control over the writer/streams.